# Increase Postgres block size from Docker Container not Source

Tags: postgresql, docker

Hi is there a way to increase the block size of a Postgresql table from a docker container? I read you can change the block size if you compile it from source but can't find any info if the Postgresql is in a docker image already.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you build your container. If you build PostgreSQL from source, you can change the block size, otherwise you cannot.

But stop worrying about that. You should not change the data block size of PostgreSQL. Few enough people do that, so that your chances of hitting some arcane software bug are increased.